# another twitter oAuth cURL access token request that fails

Tags: php, curl, twitter

The following function gives a validation error instead of the token:

> *failed to validate oAuth signature and token*

```
 function request_token()
 {
  // Set url
  $url = $this->site.$this->request_token_path; // http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token

  // Params to pass to twitter and create signature
     $params['oauth_consumer_key'] = $this->consumerKey;
     $params['oauth_token'] = '';
     $params['oauth_nonce'] = SHA1(time());
     $params['oauth_timestamp'] = time();
     $params['oauth_signature_method'] = $this->signatureMethod; // HMAC-SHA1;
     $params['oauth_version'] = $this->version; // 1.0
     ksort($params);

     //print "<pre>"; print_r($params); print "</pre>";

     // Create Signature
     $concatenatedParams = '';
     foreach($params as $k => $v){
      $concatenatedParams .= "{$k}={$v}&"; 
     }
     $concatenatedParams = substr($concatenatedParams,0,-1);

     $signatureBaseString = "POST&".urlencode($url)."&".urlencode($concatenatedParams);
     $params['oauth_signature'] = base64_encode(hash_hmac('SHA1', $signatureBaseString, $this->secret."&", TRUE));

  // Do cURL
  $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
   $exec = curl_exec ($ch);
   $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
  curl_close ($ch);

     print $exec;

    //print "<pre>"; print_r($info); print "</pre>";
 }
```

Comment: Just a heads up.  Twitter is having issues with oAuth.  This may not be your issue.

http://dev.twitter.com/status

Comment: thanks - I dont think its that tho...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Below is what Ive put together so far and it works :-)

```
    class Twitauth
    {
      var $key = '';
      var $secret = '';

      var $request_token = "https://twitter.com/oauth/request_token";

    function Twitauth($config)
    {
        $this->key = $config['key']; // consumer key from twitter
        $this->secret = $config['secret']; // secret from twitter
    }

    function getRequestToken()
    {
        // Default params
        $params = array(
            "oauth_version" => "1.0",
            "oauth_nonce" => time(),
            "oauth_timestamp" => time(),
            "oauth_consumer_key" => $this->key,
            "oauth_signature_method" => "HMAC-SHA1"
         );

         // BUILD SIGNATURE
            // encode params keys, values, join and then sort.
            $keys = $this->_urlencode_rfc3986(array_keys($params));
            $values = $this->_urlencode_rfc3986(array_values($params));
            $params = array_combine($keys, $values);
            uksort($params, 'strcmp');

            // convert params to string 
            foreach ($params as $k => $v) {$pairs[] = $this->_urlencode_rfc3986($k).'='.$this->_urlencode_rfc3986($v);}
            $concatenatedParams = implode('&', $pairs);

            // form base string (first key)
            $baseString= "GET&".$this->_urlencode_rfc3986($this->request_token)."&".$this->_urlencode_rfc3986($concatenatedParams);
            // form secret (second key)
            $secret = $this->_urlencode_rfc3986($this->secret)."&";
            // make signature and append to params
            $params['oauth_signature'] = $this->_urlencode_rfc3986(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $baseString, $secret, TRUE)));

         // BUILD URL
            // Resort
            uksort($params, 'strcmp');
            // convert params to string 
            foreach ($params as $k => $v) {$urlPairs[] = $k."=".$v;}
            $concatenatedUrlParams = implode('&', $urlPairs);
            // form url
            $url = $this->request_token."?".$concatenatedUrlParams;

         // Send to cURL
         print $this->_http($url);          
    }

    function _http($url, $post_data = null)
    {       
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

        if(isset($post_data))
        {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
        }

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $this->http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        $this->last_api_call = $url;
        curl_close($ch);

        return $response;
    }

    function _urlencode_rfc3986($input)
    {
        if (is_array($input)) {
            return array_map(array('Twitauth', '_urlencode_rfc3986'), $input);
        }
        else if (is_scalar($input)) {
            return str_replace('+',' ',str_replace('%7E', '~', rawurlencode($input)));
        }
        else{
            return '';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: nice! it works, there is a "print" instead of a "return" at the end of getRequestToken method.

Comment: I am trying to get this thing working in C#(don't know PHP) so i am a little bit confused.Is var $secret, secret consumer key from twitter ?

Comment: I'm a little late bu what is the point of
`if (is_array($input)) {
            return array_map(array('Twitauth', '_urlencode_rfc3986'), $input);
        }`

Comment: This doesn't work unless you follow the additional instructions at http://stackoverflow.com/a/4199002/389976

Comment: Holy Moly! Thanks! I've been looking for ages to find one that I can use without using cURL, and I just removed everything in the `_http` function and replaced it with `$response=file_get_contents($url)` and to my surprise, it worked!!

Comment: How would you use this code? The Twitter API says the parameters of OUR request should be encoded in the signature and I don't even see a way to pass our request into this

Answer (score 5):

not sure if your still looking into this, or if it will work for you, but i had a similar setup and had the same issue. I eventually found i was urlencoding one to many times.
Try commenting out this section:

```
 $keys = $this->_urlencode_rfc3986(array_keys($params));
        $values = $this->_urlencode_rfc3986(array_values($params));
        $params = array_combine($keys, $values);
```

Worked for me, so maybe it will help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/195192/good-bye should modify his post , thank you for this insight on his answer!

Answer (score 2):

I'll admit this isn't really an answer, but if you can, use the PECL OAuth package. [Rasmus Lerdorf wrote a tutorial on how to use it](http://toys.lerdorf.com/archives/50-Using-pecloauth-to-post-to-Twitter.html) and it got me around this same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue, what I was missing is passing header in to the curl request. As shown in this question, I was also sending the $header = array('Expect:'), which was the problem in my case. I started sending signature in header with other data as below and it solved the case for me.

```
$header = calculateHeader($parameters, 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token');

function calculateHeader(array $parameters, $url)
    {
        // redefine
        $url = (string) $url;

        // divide into parts
        $parts = parse_url($url);

        // init var
        $chunks = array();

        // process queries
        foreach($parameters as $key => $value) $chunks[] = str_replace('%25', '%', urlencode_rfc3986($key) . '="' . urlencode_rfc3986($value) . '"');

        // build return
        $return = 'Authorization: OAuth realm="' . $parts['scheme'] . '://' . $parts['host'] . $parts['path'] . '", ';
        $return .= implode(',', $chunks);

        // prepend name and OAuth part
        return $return;
    }

function urlencode_rfc3986($value)
    {
        if(is_array($value)) return array_map('urlencode_rfc3986', $value);
        else
        {
            $search = array('+', ' ', '%7E', '%');
            $replace = array('%20', '%20', '~', '%25');

            return str_replace($search, $replace, urlencode($value));
        }
    }
```