# How to generate OAuth signature with php for Twitter API?

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

Actually it is not a php question it's more about OAuth.
I'm trying to understand how to generate the OAuth sign key. 
I read the Twitter Docs and tried the example, but I couldn't understand how to use the SHA1.

Should I use SHA1 on the base string with or without the secret_key?
I tried many variations but the sign key was different form the one in the example.

This is my code:

```
function request_token(){

    $headers = 'POST&';
    $headers .= urlencode('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token');
    $headers .= '%26oauth_callback%3d'.urlencode($this->oauth_callback);
    $headers .= '%26oauth_consumer_key%3d'.urlencode($this->oauth_consumer_key);
    $headers .= '%26oauth_nonce%3d'.urlencode($this->oauth_nonce);
    $headers .= '%26oauth_signature_method%3d'.urlencode($this->oauth_signature_method);
    $headers .= '%26oauth_timestamp%3d'.urlencode($this->oauth_timestamp);

    $request_token_url = 'http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token?';
    $sha = sha1($headers);
    $url = $request_token_url.$sha.$this->consumer_secret.'&';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST      ,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_PUT,true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
```

}

Thanks

Comment: Well, for starters, replace all those "+=" with ".=".  The "." operator is used for concatenation in PHP.

Comment: No, not " .=. ", only: " .= "

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend using [Abraham's Open Source OAuth solutio](https://twitteroauth.com)n rather than trying to write your own.

[(GitHub)](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to see this working solution [another twitter oAuth cURL access token request that fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295466/another-twitter-oauth-curl-access-token-request-that-fails/3327391#3327391)