# Twitter Oauth Lib.... another once

Tags: php, api, twitter, oauth

firstly I know there are plenty of oauth libs out there, and I have thought about using them, but decidede not to, so I am writing my own just for the heck of it.  I am having an issue with signing the request though... some help?

```
function signRequest($secret, $baseUrl){
    return base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $baseUrl, $secret, TRUE));
}

function getRequestToken(){
    $urlParams = array(
        "oauth_consumer_key"=>$this->consumer_key,
        "oauth_signature_method"=>$this->oauth_signature_method,
        "oauth_timestamp"=>time(),
        "oauth_nonce"=>time(),
        "oauth_version"=>$this->oauth_version
    );
    uksort($urlParams, 'strcmp');

    foreach($urlParams as $k=>$v){
        $joinedParams[] = $k."=".$v;
    }
    $joinedParams = implode("&", $joinedParams);


    $baseString = "POST&".rawurlencode($this->request_token_url)."&".rawurlencode($joinedParams);
    $secret = $this->consumer_secret."&";

    $urlParams['oauth_signature'] = $this->signRequest($secret, $baseUrl);
    uksort($urlParams, 'strcmp');
    foreach($urlParams as $k => $v){
        $urlPairs[] = $k."=".$v;
    }
    $concatenatedUrlParams = implode('&', $urlPairs);
    $url = $this->request_token_url."?".$concatenatedUrlParams;
    echo $url;

}
```

I am new to the whole signing of request thing.  I was able to connect to the twitter api using the following link though.  Mine is essentially a rewritten cody of the following answer...

[another twitter oAuth cURL access token request that fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295466/another-twitter-oauth-curl-access-token-request-that-fails)

Comment: I think you forgot to tell us what's actually going wrong.

Comment: I think I am signing the request incorrectly...

Comment: What makes you think this?  Are you getting a specific error message?

Comment: just a response that the oauth fails.  Keep in mind that all of the same information (keys, secrets, url params, etc) work with the unaltered version of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295466/another-twitter-oauth-curl-access-token-request-that-fails

Comment: @Justin, it seems you based your work on the original question, not on the accepted answer.  In particular, you're missing the [RFC 3986 URL encoding](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) of the parameters, at the minimum.

Comment: Yeah.  I have been looking back at the original source, and it seems that you are right.  I thought I was able to do it that way, apparently.  Not.  I appreciate your help.  Still not 100% sure thats messing up, but I will keep looking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to force your oauth parameters like a token.

You need to build an "Authorization" header, and send it to twitter for a request token. I've destroyed your code's class functionality, but as a single php file, it works fine.

Check out the differences, and try to embed them into your own class.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

getRequestToken ();

function signRequest($secret, $baseString) {
    return base64_encode ( hash_hmac ( 'sha1', $baseString, $secret, TRUE ) );
}

function getRequestToken() {
    $urlParams = array (
        "oauth_consumer_key" => "5P7F5qtIUujg3KtLxxxxxx", //$this->consumer_key,
        "oauth_signature_method" => "HMAC-SHA1", //$this->oauth_signature_method,
        "oauth_timestamp" => time(),
        "oauth_nonce" => md5 ( uniqid ( rand(), true ) ), // don't use time for nonce :)
        "oauth_version" => "1.0" //$this->oauth_version
    );
    ksort ( $urlParams ); // don't need uksort, ksort is enough


    foreach ( $urlParams as $k => $v ) {
        $joinedParams [] = $k . "=" . $v;
    }
    $joinedParams = implode ( "&", $joinedParams );

    $baseString = "GET&" . rawurlencode ( "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token" ) . "&" . rawurlencode ( $joinedParams );
    $secret = rawurlencode ( "3q017y6ir8Rxxxxxxx" ) . "&"; //$this->consumer_secret."&";

    // We need to use the $baseString, not an url
    $urlParams ['oauth_signature'] = rawurlencode ( signRequest ( $secret, $baseString ) );

    // Another ksort is not needed, it is ok for signature to be at the end, however:
    ksort($urlParams);

    // We need to build an array of headers for CURL
    $urlParts = parse_url ( "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token" );
    $header = array ('Expect:' );
    $oauthHeader = 'Authorization: OAuth realm="' . $urlParts ['path'] . '", ';
    foreach ( $urlParams as $name => $value ) {
        $oauthHeader .= "{$name}=\"{$value}\", ";
    }
    $header [] = substr ( $oauthHeader, 0, - 2 );

    // Ask Twitter for a request token
    $ch = curl_init ( "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token" );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    $content = curl_exec ( $ch );
    curl_close ( $ch );

    // Create the url from the curl answer
    parse_str($content, $output);
    $url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=" . $output["oauth_token"];
    echo $url ;

}
```

Comment: Wow, after all of that searching, I finally fund a nice clean cut response.  It is so annoying trying to pick apart full class oAuth libs to try to get some basic functionally.  Thanks for the quick and simple response.

Comment: I was trying to write the whole process but this comment box is small. Plus I remembered that Twitter had a page explaining all the OAuth process in great detail and order : [link](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth)

Comment: Yeah, I have been reading that page, I still had those questions though.  Thanks again.