# Get contacts using Yahoo Contacts API

Tags: php, oauth, yahoo-api

I followed these steps "http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-auth-flow.html" and I got oauth token and GUID from authenticated user.
Now I am trying retrieve all contacts through GUID as I have seen on searchs for web using this url "http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/GUID_HERE/contacts" and passing authorization data via headers but I just get this response:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><yahoo:errorxmlns:yahoo='http://yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng' xml:lang='en-US'><yahoo:description>Please provide valid credentials. OAuth oauth_problem="signature_invalid", realm="yahooapis.com"</yahoo:description></yahoo:error><!-- ws129.socdir.sp2.yahoo.com uncompressed/chunked Tue Aug 28 06:22:40 PDT 2012 -->
```

I am performing the request using cURL (PHP) like is written here "http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-make-request.html" (I have checked and I am using my consumer secret as ouath_signature):

```
$header = array(
'GET http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/' . $guid[1] . '/contacts',
'Authorization: OAuth realm="yahooapis.com", '.
                                     'oauth_consumer_key="'.$yahoo_consumer_key.'", '.
                                     'oauth_nonce="'.uniqid().'", '.
                                     'oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", '.
                                     'oauth_timestamp="'.time().'", '.
                                     'oauth_token="'.$ouathToken[1].'", '.
                                     'oauth_version="1.0", '.
                                     'oauth_signature="'.$yahoo_consumer_secret.'"');
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
              CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,
              CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
              CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
              //CURLOPT_HTTPGET => true,
              CURLOPT_URL => 'http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/' . $guid[1] . '/contacts',
              CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header
    ));
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 2):

The OAuth Signature isn't just the consumer secret. Yahoo has some [documentation on how sign the request](http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-signing.html) and that's what goes in the oauth_signature field.

Comment: I have concatenated consumer secret with token secret from many ways (with '&', without, before, after..) and the response is the same, do a test and you will see.

Comment: You need to sign the request with HMAC_SHA1 (as listed in your signature_method) and the key is CONSUMER_SECRET&TOKEN_SECRET. See the section in my above link titled "Signing Requests using HMAC-SHA1" to see how they want you to do the signing.

Comment: I understood but I dont know how to generate this "base string", I have to use bese64_encode from PHP? with which values? Can you guide me how to generate the oauth signature?

Comment: If you want to understand the OAuth Signture, [here is one of the best articles](http://blog.andydenmark.com/2009/03/how-to-build-oauth-consumer.html) (Note: Its not for Twitter, but it does a great job explaining it) I've seen on describing it. If you want to see a working example, here is a [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295466/another-twitter-oauth-curl-access-token-request-that-fails) that has some sample code you can use.

Comment: I have read developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-signing.html and now I am creating what I think to be a valid signature, see my code: pastebin.com/ZagMBrbM But, I am still getting the error: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> <yahoo:error xmlns:yahoo='yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng'; xml:lang='en-US'> <yahoo:description>Please provide valid credentials. OAuth oauth_problem="signature_invalid", realm="yahooapis.com"</yahoo:description> </yahoo:error> Where is the error?

Answer (score 1):

Seems the signature created is wrong.For create signature first create base string which is created by normalizing your url.

For more details  about base string  visit  http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-signing.html.
http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#anchor16

After creating a base string create a signature key which is developed by concatenating COSUMER SECRET and token secret with &.Like this,

$signatureKey = CONSUMER_SECRET."&".{yourtokensecret};

Then for create signature try this code:
  $signature = urlencode(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1',{baseString}, $signatureKey, true)));

Comment: I have read http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-signing.html and now I am creating what I think to be a valid signature, see my code: http://pastebin.com/ZagMBrbM

But, I am still getting the error: 

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<yahoo:error xmlns:yahoo='http://yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng'
  xml:lang='en-US'>
  <yahoo:description>Please provide valid credentials. OAuth oauth_problem="signature_invalid", realm="yahooapis.com"</yahoo:description>
</yahoo:error>

Where is the error?

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent signing function available [here](https://github.com/joechung/oauth_yahoo/blob/master/oauth_helper.php).