# Twitter API oAuth failed signature when adding callback url

Tags: twitter, oauth, callback

I'm using this code/guide [another twitter oAuth cURL access token request that fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295466/another-twitter-oauth-curl-access-token-request-that-fails/3327391#3327391) to test signing my request to the API. I'm still trying to go through step 1 of [this](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter)

*Note: the keys are just random, they're not real :)*

when I try to make a request without oauth_callback I get a valid response from the api

> https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token?oauth_consumer_key=nHb2kSQ2CD9MW1MdW5VeQ&oauth_nonce=1356902849&oauth_signature=MbvhwGiNPKQR0klUPx9fsmUtdJY%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1356902849&oauth_version=1.0

when I add the oauth_callback string (mandatory to let users sign with a redirect!) I get "Failed to validate oauth signature and token"

> https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token?oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%2Ftest%2F&oauth_consumer_key=nHb2kSQ2CD9MW1MdW5VeQ&oauth_nonce=1356902915&oauth_signature=2WTaI9jXNBaDd7f8AqIe6y3%2Beno%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1356902915&oauth_version=1.0

I mean there's no difference between the two URLs, they both go through the same execution and they respect the signing method. 
How to fix it?

yes I added `http://127.0.0.1/test/` as callback url in the twitter app settings.

Thank you

Comment: Also check that your time is synced by a NTP server, because the token are time sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. The problem was that even though the callback URL was sent correctly using the querystring method or headers as you can see on the links, it was also double escaped when creating the signature from the basestring. Since the documentation is pretty bad regarding this I didn't think that you shouldn't double escape it as well like other oauth_* parameters (aka percentage encode the "&"s).

Comment: So are you saying that you MUST double escape?  or you MUST NOT?  Too many negatives in there, and as a result your explanation is unclear. `I didn't think that you shouldn't double escape it ...` = does that mean you should or should not double escape?

Comment: sorry:P You MUST NOT double escape the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set up the callback url in the twitter application settings?

If you don't set that up, the api may fail.

Check it from [here](https://dev.twitter.com/apps):

[image]

Also check that your time is in sync (use an NTP server); see: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1043

Comment: yes I've set the callback url (I wrote it) and the time is synched (otherwise why would it work without the callback?). Anyway -anything- without "://" in the callback is validated...

Comment: are you sure that the callback url is URLEncoded? because this could be a good reason to invalidate the request. Yes it is. I saw from your question, it looks ok.

Comment: so what else could it be? Do I have to send the callback in the request even if set in the app settings?

Comment: I ran out of hypotesis. Twitter oAuth API is hard to start. You may try to find a working example in your language (php I guess). It could be some encoding issue on the URL, imho; I've read a lot of things regarding twitter peculiarities. I use Twitter4J and it took me sometime to get rid of the oAuth things, even with samples and a Java API ready to use. If you're doing all by yourself, pain is granted.

Comment: I can see it's a PITA! What's strange is that in the documentation it says callback URL is required for oauth/request_token but my requests only work without it or with something non-URL. If its required it should fail without it!

Answer (score 1):

Agreed that twitter API is badly documented :)

**Follow this rule:**

1. If your **oauth_callback** does not contain any query string = Nothing funky is required.
2. If your **oauth_callback** has any query string parameters = **URL Encode** the query string parameters separately.

Hope this explains.