# Twitter oauth/request_token API using Fiddler results in 401 error

Tags: twitter, oauth, fiddler

I am trying to use fiddler to test the oauth/request_token api but am getting a 'Failed to validate oauth signature and token' 401 error. I copied the authorization header values directly from my application and added an oauth_callback header. I am trying to follow the example in the following documentation:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/oauth/request_token. 

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

REQUEST:

POST https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token HTTP/1.1
Authorization: OAuth oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A61921%2Ftwitter%2Fprocesscallback",
  oauth_consumer_key="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
 oauth_nonce="53891723ad7b32501c669d97f56c6d47",
 oauth_signature="qzN516EVspIA0NWBbpND83YcTr4%3D",
 
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
oauth_timestamp="1402955245",
oauth_token="2514015781-KqTbOPPag7p0CYQ6xByIibV3WEk8xLsWrhb9U4M",
oauth_version="1.0"
Host: api.twitter.com
Content-Length: 0

RESPONSE:
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0
content-length: 44
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
date: Mon, 16 Jun 2014 21:54:56 GMT
expires: Tue, 31 Mar 1981 05:00:00 GMT
last-modified: Mon, 16 Jun 2014 21:54:56 GMT
pragma: no-cache
server: tfe
set-cookie: _twitter_sess=BAh7CDoPY3JlYXRlZF9hdGwrCEIJraZGAToHaWQiJTlmOTQ3Y2MyYWNlMTkx%250AYTMyYzVlZmYyMTA4ZjU4ZTdkIgpmbGFzaElDOidBY3Rpb25Db250cm9sbGVy%250AOjpGbGFzaDo6Rmxhc2hIYXNoewAGOgpAdXNlZHsA--3afebfe1105e8a7315baba72651e76a24f53e6d2; domain=.twitter.com; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
set-cookie: guest_id=v1%3A140295569643962216; Domain=.twitter.com; Path=/; Expires=Wed, 15-Jun-2016 21:54:56 UTC
status: 401 Unauthorized
strict-transport-security: max-age=631138519
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-mid: d31abfd0b6cbb0aa6434a6ffc6efdfac089ab0a5
x-runtime: 0.01273
x-transaction: 2dd94ca53f553801
x-ua-compatible: IE=edge,chrome=1
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block

Failed to validate oauth signature and token

Comment: You do not send an oauth_token parameter when you are obtaining a request token.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14094893/twitter-api-oauth-failed-signature-when-adding-callback-url looks similar. Also, is the callback URL supposed to be an input into the calculation of the signature field?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. Unfortunately, I am still getting the same error message.

Jon, I removed the oauth_token header.

Eric, The callback URL was not double escaped. I did, however, change it to http://127.0.0.1/twitter/processcallback and added this url to my settings as my callback url since localhost urls are not allowed for this setting.
I am not sure how the signature is generated. I am getting the header field values including the oauth_signature header by going to:
Twitter Apps->My App->TestOauth->See Oauth Signature for my Request.

Comment: My latest attempt looks like this and is still returning the  'Failed to validate oauth signature and token' 401 error:

POST https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token HTTP/1.1
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="Mc8SVb1ARxiI39wOSUvArzn3J", 
oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%2Ftwitter%2Fprocesscallback",  
oauth_nonce="67685d870d324c9667d8480d1fa36068", 
oauth_signature="HvZ8bdmp9PWIkKESNBWPkVfpJEQ%3D", 
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", 
oauth_timestamp="1403027415",  
oauth_version="1.0"

Host: api.twitter.com
Content-Length: 0